# Android - BroadcastReceiver does not work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, forceclose

When I `Force Close` an application, does the `BroadcastReceiver` keeps listening for intents?

I have this `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements Variables {

    CheckConexion cc;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context contxt, Intent intent) {

        // Cuando hay un evento, lo diferenciamos y hacemos una acción.

        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Sms sms = new Sms(null, contxt);
            sms.uploadNewSms(intent);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW)) {
            // st.batterylow(contxt);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) {
            /*
             * try { new PhoneState(contxt).battery(intent.getIntExtra("level",
             * 0)); } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             */// Nothing at the moment
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
            Log.i("******", "Battery on");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
            // st.power(0, contxt);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)) {
            Database db = new Database(contxt);
            if (db.open().Preferences(4)) {
                Uri data = intent.getData();
                new ListApps(contxt).import_app(intent, contxt, data,
                        intent.getAction());
            }
            db.close();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            cc = new CheckConexion(contxt);
            if (cc.isOnline()) {

                Database db = new Database(contxt);
                db.open();
                if (db.move() == 1) {
                    new UploadOffline(contxt);
                }
                db.close();

            }
        }

    }

    public void register(Context c) {
        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction(SMS_RECEIVED);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        i.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        c.registerReceiver(this, i);
        IntentFilter apps = new IntentFilter();
        apps.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
        apps.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
        apps.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
        apps.addDataScheme("package");
        c.registerReceiver(this, apps);
    }

    public void unregister(Context c) {
        c.unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
}
```

I call register and then I `Force Close`. I want to keep the `BroadcastRecever` working and listening for the incoming intents.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcast receivers will not work after force closing your app. This is built into the OS by design.

Comment: That is not true. If you register a receiver with registerReceiver() the its life time is tied to the life time of of the object registered it. Therefore if you kill the application, the receiver will no longer work. A service wont work. You should register your receiver in the manifest of your app to make it work as you describe.

Comment: Tobias, that is not true as of API version 12. Please see http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html, section "Launch controls on stopped applications".

BroadcastReceivers will not work if the application is force stopped, even if declared in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Register your receiver in your [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html). Then it will be permanently activated (you can manually enable/disable it if you like using the package manager).